# Time format of HTML time Input type support by all browsers

Tags: html, angular, forms, time, browser

**Hi** ,

I'm working on a project with Angular /Jhipster. I have currently a problem with the input Forms,
In fact, I created an Input Form with Type="TIME". It works on my browser perfectly for example (12:24) but in other browsers, it's displayed in another form like (12:24 AM) or in some others its displayed like a normal string and not time.
How can I fix it, I want it to be displayed in all other browsers like mine.

```
<input id="timeVar" type="time" name="usr_time" value="09:36"
(change)="setDefValue($event,'usr_time')" required pattern="[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}">
```

Thanks !

Comment: checkout the supported browser versions here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: is there any way to make it supported by all browsers? that needs to be displayed equally in all browsers!

Comment: Either you need to create your own custom time input or use any existing library like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if there is any solution for that. I see, you also tried with pattern. Other alternative if you are willing to try, then search for time-picker online. Maybe this should help and i think it will make standardize time pattern in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular project, you can use a Angular DatePipe. This is the easiest way to do this without creating your own solution.

Example : `{{valueDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}` or `{{ dateObj | date }}`.

You can choose your output. Look into documentation => example from doc.

```
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mm:ss' }}       // output is '43:11'`
```

[Angular doc to DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)